# How to always place an element at the bottom of a DIN A4 page in CSS using Puppeteer?

Tags: css, pdf, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate multi-page invoices using puppeteer and handlebars and can't figure out how to make the payment information always stick to the bottom of the last page.

Let's say I have some template HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        {{#each items}}
        <div style="page-break-after: always">{{this.val}}</div>
        {{/each}}

        <div>This should be at the bottom of the previous page.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and a function to generate a PDF like this:

```
async function generateInvoice() {
    // Generating HTML
    const data = { items: [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }] };
    const html = Handlebars.compile((await fs.readFile("./template.html")).toString());
    const compiledHTML = encodeURIComponent(html(data));

    // Setting up browser
    const browser = await Puppeteer.launch({
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${compiledHTML}`, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    });

    // Writing PDf to out.pdf
    await page.pdf({
        path: "out.pdf",
        format: "A4",
    });

    await browser.close();
}
```

How could I modify that code to reflect what I want to do?

I've toyed around with the `page-break` attributes and absolute positioning but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `footerTemplate`, `headerTemplate` and `displayHeaderFooter` fields in `page.pdf(...)` for things like this.

The configuration that I use:

```
page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: await componentHeader(),
  footerTemplate: componentFooter(),
  printBackground:true,
  format: 'A4',
  margin:{
  top: 140,
  bottom: 50,
  right: 15,
  left: 15,
})
```

componentFooter

```
<footer style="padding: 10px;font-size: 10px; text-align: center;width:100vw">
    Page <span class="pageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalPages"></span>
</footer>
```

header would be the same
just need to remember set the margin correctly and the font-size so that it will show

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not working on this anymore and won't check it, but following the documentation it really should work: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions